# BaseActivity mvvm architecture android, viewmodel not initialized

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding

I am trying to write a base activity with code like this

```
abstract class BaseActivity<T : ViewDataBinding, V : BaseViewModel> : AppCompatActivity(), HasSupportFragmentInjector {

val NO_VIEW_MODEL_BINDING_VARIABLE = -1

private lateinit var mViewModel: V
private lateinit var mViewDataBinding: T

@Inject
lateinit var mViewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory

@Inject
lateinit var mFragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

abstract fun getViewModelBindingVariable() : Int

@LayoutRes
abstract fun getLayoutId() : Int

fun getDataBinding() : T {
  return mViewDataBinding
}

fun getViewModel() : V {
    return mViewModel
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    performDataBinding()
    provideViewModel()

}

override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {
    return mFragmentInjector
}

private fun performDataBinding() {
    mViewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, getLayoutId())
    if (getViewModelBindingVariable() != NO_VIEW_MODEL_BINDING_VARIABLE) {
        setViewModelBindingVariable()
    }
}

private fun setViewModelBindingVariable() {
    mViewDataBinding.setVariable(getViewModelBindingVariable(), mViewModel)
    mViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings()
}

private fun provideViewModel() {
    val clazz: Class<V> = getViewModelClass(javaClass)
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, mViewModelFactory).get(clazz)
}

private fun getViewModelClass(aClass: Class<*>): Class<V> {
    val type = aClass.genericSuperclass

    return if (type is ParameterizedType) {
        type.actualTypeArguments[1] as Class<V>
    } else {
        getViewModelClass(aClass.superclass)
    }
}
}
```

and I also using databinding here, the problem I encountered is whenever I tried to reference the viewmodel class in my xml and return the generated value of the viewmodel by using BR.viewModel in getViewModelBindingVariable it gave an error saying that

```
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mViewModel has not been initialized
    at com.rahmat.app.newsapp.features.base.BaseActivity.setViewModelBindingVariable(BaseActivity.kt:70)
    at com.rahmat.app.newsapp.features.base.BaseActivity.performDataBinding(BaseActivity.kt:65)
    at com.rahmat.app.newsapp.features.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:53)
    at com.rahmat.app.newsapp.features.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:31)
```

This error didn't happen if I return NO_VIEW_MODEL_BINDING_VARIABLE but this made me cannot reference the viewmodel class that I want in my xml. I think there is some problem in my provideViewModel() function but I still don't know why. Any help would be much appreciated. thank you

Comment: You are calling performDataBinding() before calling provideViewModel(), thus you access mViewModel before it was initialized. Possibly reversing the order fixes your problem?

Comment: ah I see, yes it fixed the problem, now it works, thank you so much @DominikG.